Why did Robert’s face suddenly become sad?
Upon entering the room, Richard and Bush see Robert and Lawrence,
who are already debating the unionization of professors, similar to
teachers:

ROBERT: Richard. Dr. Bush. What brings you two up north?

With a sudden sadness on his face and somber music playing in the
background, Robert greets Richard and exits the room.

ROBERT: Richard, you tell Ruth I'll be down to Pasadena Thursday.

Why did Robert’s face suddenly become sad?

We can only guess, but hints are :

Richard is Ruth's husband.
Robert has an emotional affair with Ruth.
Robert will move away from Ruth soon.

Leaving a person you really care for, being alone for a while without emotional support, and, at the same time, facing the man (a friend) you "betray"1 doesn't really make you happy. Seeing Richard is probably a reminder of that situation, and instantly makes him sad.

1. Some historians say that Ruth and Robert never had a physical relationship.
